# Current Tensorflow Program creates a Dataset for NLP using Cornell's Movie Dialog Data. How can I reprogram it to support a different Dataset?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, dataset, tensorflow-datasets

This program essentially does many things. It downloads the Cornell Dialog Data Zip file and extracts it. It then reaches in and begins to load questions and answers from the datasets to a list of strings. It loads it into my training program and begins learning from the data set.

```
import os
import re
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds

# Maximum number of samples to preprocess
MAX_SAMPLES = 50000
# Maximum sentence length
MAX_LENGTH = 40


def create_datasets():
    # 1) download the datasets and unzip it.
    path_to_zip = tf.keras.utils.get_file('cornell_movie_dialogs.zip',
                                          origin='http://www.cs.cornell.edu/~cristian/data/cornell_movie_dialogs_corpus.zip',
                                          extract=True)
    # get the unzipped files' path.
    path_to_dataset = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(path_to_zip), "cornell movie-dialogs corpus")
    path_to_movie_lines = os.path.join(path_to_dataset, 'movie_lines.txt')
    path_to_movie_conversations = os.path.join(path_to_dataset, 'movie_conversations.txt')

    # 2) loads questions and answers from the datasets into a list of strings. (I think this is where it really matters)
    questions, answers = load_conversations(path_to_movie_lines, path_to_movie_conversations)

    # 3) Build tokenizer using tfds for both questions and answers
    tokenizer = tfds.deprecated.text.SubwordTextEncoder.build_from_corpus(questions + answers, target_vocab_size=2 ** 13)
    # Define start and end token to indicate the start and end of a sentence
    start_token, end_token = [tokenizer.vocab_size], [tokenizer.vocab_size + 1]
    # Vocabulary size plus start and end token
    VOCAB_SIZE = tokenizer.vocab_size + 2
    # tokenize the datasets.
    questions, answers = tokenize_and_filter(questions, answers, start_token, end_token, tokenizer)

    print('Vocab size: {}'.format(VOCAB_SIZE))
    print('Number of samples: {}'.format(len(questions)))

    # 4) convert the datasets to tf.data.Dataset format
    # decoder inputs use the previous target as input
    # remove START_TOKEN from targets
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((
        {
            'inputs': questions,
            'dec_inputs': answers[:, :-1]
        },
        {
            'outputs': answers[:, 1:]
        },
    ))
    return dataset, tokenizer


def preprocess_sentence(sentence):
    sentence = sentence.lower().strip()
    # creating a space between a word and the punctuation following it
    # eg: "he is a boy." => "he is a boy ."
    sentence = re.sub(r"([?.!,])", r" \1 ", sentence)
    sentence = re.sub(r'[" "]+', " ", sentence)
    # replacing everything with space except (a-z, A-Z, ".", "?", "!", ",")
    sentence = re.sub(r"[^a-zA-Z?.!,]+", " ", sentence)
    sentence = sentence.strip()
    # adding a start and an end token to the sentence
    return sentence


def load_conversations(path_to_movie_lines, path_to_movie_conversations):
    # dictionary of line id to text
    id2line = {}
    with open(path_to_movie_lines, errors='ignore') as file:
        lines = file.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        parts = line.replace('\n', '').split(' +++$+++ ')
        id2line[parts[0]] = parts[4]

    inputs, outputs = [], []
    with open(path_to_movie_conversations, 'r') as file:
        lines = file.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        parts = line.replace('\n', '').split(' +++$+++ ')
        # get conversation in a list of line ID
        conversation = [line[1:-1] for line in parts[3][1:-1].split(', ')]
        for i in range(len(conversation) - 1):
            inputs.append(preprocess_sentence(id2line[conversation[i]]))
            outputs.append(preprocess_sentence(id2line[conversation[i + 1]]))
            if len(inputs) >= MAX_SAMPLES:
                return inputs, outputs
    return inputs, outputs


# Tokenize, filter and pad sentences
def tokenize_and_filter(inputs, outputs, start_token, end_token, tokenizer):
    tokenized_inputs, tokenized_outputs = [], []

    for (sentence1, sentence2) in zip(inputs, outputs):
        # tokenize sentence
        sentence1 = start_token + tokenizer.encode(sentence1) + end_token
        sentence2 = start_token + tokenizer.encode(sentence2) + end_token
        # check tokenized sentence max length
        if len(sentence1) <= MAX_LENGTH and len(sentence2) <= MAX_LENGTH:
            tokenized_inputs.append(sentence1)
            tokenized_outputs.append(sentence2)

    # pad tokenized sentences
    tokenized_inputs = tf.keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences(
        tokenized_inputs, maxlen=MAX_LENGTH, padding='post')
    tokenized_outputs = tf.keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences(
        tokenized_outputs, maxlen=MAX_LENGTH, padding='post')

    return tokenized_inputs, tokenized_outputs


if __name__ == "__main__":
    tf.executing_eagerly()
    create_datasets()
```

The problem is that I want to use a different data set but it doesn't seem to like it when I overwrite the txt files inside with other data as it isn't in a similar structure as the Cornell Data files. Here is an example of how these are structured...

```
L1045 +++$+++ u0 +++$+++ m0 +++$+++ BIANCA +++$+++ They do not!
L1044 +++$+++ u2 +++$+++ m0 +++$+++ CAMERON +++$+++ They do to!
L985 +++$+++ u0 +++$+++ m0 +++$+++ BIANCA +++$+++ I hope so.
L984 +++$+++ u2 +++$+++ m0 +++$+++ CAMERON +++$+++ She okay?
L925 +++$+++ u0 +++$+++ m0 +++$+++ BIANCA +++$+++ Let's go.
```

Other data sets are structured with different annotations and this program doesn't like it when I bring those data txt files instead of the Cornell structured ones. Any advice on what I could do to change the program to support new kinds of data?

Comment: Write a program that modifies the new dataset to be in the same format as the Cornell one.

Comment: @gobrewers14 The thing is, I am unsure of how to do that. Or even where to begin. Cornell's data is in such a unique format. Do you think that I could I can modify the program in such a way where it can take questions and answers out in a different way rather than changing the structure of the other text files?

Comment: How were you able to write this code to parse the Cornell dataset but cannot write code to parse the new dataset?

Comment: @gobrewers14 It's based on documentation and examples online. I wasn't able to figure out how I could apply the same to another data set.

Comment: @gobrewers14 I would want to use datasets like Blog Authorship Corpus or other datasets in TXT format here: [link](https://github.com/niderhoff/nlp-datasets) It would make the chatbot a lot better than it is now.

Comment: I would suggest stepping through `load_conversations` line by line until you understand what it does. Then take that knowledge and try to implement a solution for your new dataset. And when/if you run into a specific issue, come back here and post your question. But dumping code you didn't write nor understand yourself and asking a vague question about how to refactor the code isn't really what this site is for.

Comment: @gobrewers14 good point. Thank you very much.